# In Objective-C how can I display a uint8_t variable in binary?

Tags: objective-c, printf

Say I start with:

```
uint8_t x = 0x12;
```

For debugging purposes I want to "print" it in binary (using NSLog) so I see: 000010010.

Is there a way to do that in Objective-C? The closest I got is using %o format, which gives 22 and then manually translate that to binary.

Also what about uint16_t y = 0x1234; or uint32_t z = 0x12345678; ?

Comment: Do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373093/how-to-print-binary-number-via-printf).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work fine:

```
- (void)printIntInBinary:(int)num {
    NSMutableString *binaryResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    while(num) {
        [binaryResult insertString:num&1?@"1":@"0" atIndex:0];
        num>>=1;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",binaryResult);
}
```

Works for all the examples you posted!

Comment: Thanks! Nice and simple but it doesn't print the leading zeroes. The while loop stops before inserting them.