# Looping through Bits C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to loop through the bits of an unsigned char, but I'm not sure where to start, eventually, I'll perform other bitwise operating on the bits, such as ~ and xor..etc.

Comment: do you consider operate on all of them, at one time?

Answer (score 11):

Looping over bits can be done in several ways:

- You can do a destructive loop, when you shift the value, and test the initial or the final bit, depending on the order in which you would like to enumerate bits, or
- You can do a non-destructive loop, when you use bitwise AND to test the number with a single-bit *mask*, produced by left-shifting `1`.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
unsigned int bits = ...;
while (bits) {
    if (bits & 1) {
        // Current bit is set to 1
    } else {
        // Current bit is set to 0
    }
    bits >>= 1;
}
```

If you want to continue working with bits after you reach zero, make a separate counter.

Here is an example of the second approach:

```
unsigned int bits = ...;
for (int pos = 0 ; pos != 16 ; pos++) {
    if (bits & (1 << pos)) {
        // Current bit is set to 1
    } else {
        // Current bit is set to 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is no good if there is an action to be taken for 0 bits past the last 1 bit, since it stops when `bits` is 0.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's a fair point - I mentioned it to the OP, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This function will allow you to iterate through all set bits in a word:

```
inline size_t next_bit(uint64_t bf, size_t bit) {
    return ctz(bf & ~((1UL << bit) -1));
}
```

The `ctz` function counts the number of trailing zeroes which should be provided by your compiler as a built-in function. For gcc and llvm, you can use the following (note that `ctz` is undefined for `0` on x86 hence the fixup):

```
inline size_t ctz(uint64_t x) { return x ? __builtin_ctzll(x) : 64; }
```

Here's an example of how to use it in a for-loop:

```
for (size_t i = next_bit(bf, 0); i < 64; i = next_bit(bf, i + 1))
    // the i-th bit is set.
```

The function works by clearing away all the bits preceding the `i`th bit and counting the number of trailing zeroes which will provide you with the next set bit after the `i`th bit. Clearing the bits is accomplished by first shifting a bit into the `i`th position, subtracting one which sets all the bits lower then the `i`th bit. We can then `NOT` the mask to get all the bits after `i` so that an `AND` op will remove all the bits after `i`. `ctz` does the rest.

It's a bit (pun intended) overkill for an unsigned char but I couldn't resist. Honestly, for 8-bit words, you're better off with a simple while loop as proposed in the other answers.

Comment: I was looking for a way of using least number of CPU cycles. Doesn't this method use up a lot of cycles compared to masking or shifting?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from lowest to highest bit, you can loop like so:

```
unsigned char somebyte = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i, somebyte >>= 1) {
    if (somebyte & 0x1) {
        // Do stuff for 1 bit
    } else {
        // Do stuff for 0 bit
    }
}
```

That's a really general use case though; typically, you want to parallelize your work (operate on a whole byte at a time), or only operate on the 1 bits (and stop when you run out instead of finishing all eight loops), etc. More context is needed to solve specific problems rather than general looping. [Many specific problems are most efficiently solved with clever bit twiddling hacks.](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define BIT(a,b)    (a & (1<<b))

void printBits(unsigned char c){
    int i;

    char bits[9];
    for( i=0;i<8;i++){
        bits[i]=BIT(c,i)?'1':'0';

    }
    bits[8]=0;
    char *fmt=isalpha(c)
            ?"'%c'\t= '%s'\n"
            :" %d\t= '%s'\n";
    printf(fmt,c,bits);
}


int main(){


    printBits('A');
    printBits('B');
    printBits(1);
    printBits(2);
    printBits(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to access individual bits use macros   BIT(char,BitPos)  , where BitPos is in the range of [0-7] for char (BYTE).

Answer (score 0):

This method allows maps the indicies of an array with values in an enumerator, regardless of the order of elements or how many elements are stored in the array:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint8_t, CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBit) {
    CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitTorchLevel       = 1<< 0,
    CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitLensPosition     = 1<< 1,
    CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitExposureDuration = 1<< 2,
    CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitISO              = 1<< 3,
    CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitZoomFactor       = 1<< 4,
};

typedef CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBit CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitMask;
CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitMask mask = (CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitTorchLevel |
                                                         CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitLensPosition|
                                                         CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitExposureDuration|
                                                         CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitISO|
                                                         CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitZoomFactor);
                                                             
do{
    printf("mask\t==\t%d\n", (CaptureDeviceConfigurationControlPropertyBitMask)mask);
} while((mask ^= mask & (0- mask)) != 0.0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Void PrintBits(unsigned int no)
{
Unsigned int mask = 0x8000;//=1000 0000 0000 0000 for 16 bit integers
For(I=0;I<16;I++){
    If((i&mask)!=0)printf("1");
    Else printf ("0");
    Mask>>=1;
    If(i%4==0)printf (" ");
}

}
```

If you don't understand this code please comment, I'm 24x7 online for you.

Comment: If you can print int you can print anything. For char use mask 0x80, also for loop limit to 8 iterations.

Comment: use this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280654/c-printing-bits), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024389/print-an-int-in-binary-representation-using-c), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373093/how-to-print-binary-number-via-printf)