# Losing LSB when shifting a binary string

Tags: string, char, shift

Hi I currently have a binary string which I am shifting once to the left.

```
char bin[] = "01010001";

  printf("Binary number = %s \n", bin);
  printf("Binary number shifted by 1 to the left = %s \n", (bin+1) );
```

Output:

```
    Binary number = 01010001
    Binary number shifted by 1 to the left = 1010001
```

The shifted version should be: 10100010 rather than 1010001. Does anybody know why I am always losing the least significant bit?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is written in C?

Then you are not performing a shift operation on bits here.

Instead you declare a char array (pointer) and increment it's pointer position by one (via `bin+1`).
The result is what you see. The leftmost character is being cut off.

For real shift operations use numeric variables, the shift operator (`<<`, `>>`) and print the variable in a binary representation (find a way e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373093/how-to-print-binary-number-via-printf)).